# A mathematical paper of Edouard Lucas

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I recently came across a paper by the mathematician [Edouard Lucas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Lucas),

"Recherches sur l’analyse indéterminée et l’arithmétique de Diophante" Moulins: Desrosiers, 1873; reprint Paris: Blanchard, 1961.

I'm looking for the above paper, either downloadable or purchasable copy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read this online or download as PDF: https://books.google.com/books/about/Recherches_sur_l_analyse_ind%C3%A9termin%C3%A9e.html?id=OP4pmQEACAAJ